# Primefaces: Not able to center align p:chart

Tags: css, primefaces

My xhtml code is

```
    <p:outputPanel id="topperchartcont">
        <p:outputPanel rendered="#{performanceStaffController.reportType == 'TP'}">
            <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 10%">
                </td>
                <td style="width: 80%; text-align:center">
                    <h:panelGrid column="1">
                        <h:panelGroup style="width:80%; display:block; text-align:center">
                            <table style="border:1px solid #D8D8D8">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:center">
                                    <p:chart type="bar" model="#{performanceStaffController.topperChartModel}" 
                                                rendered="#{performanceStaffController.topperChartModel != null}"
                                                style="#{performanceStaffController.perfBean.chartWidth}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 10%">
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:outputPanel>
```

I also tried without the PanelGrid/PanelGroup

```
    <p:outputPanel id="topperchartcont">
        <p:outputPanel rendered="#{performanceStaffController.reportType == 'TP'}">
            <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 10%">
                </td>
                <td style="width: 80%; text-align:center">
                            <table style="border:1px solid #D8D8D8">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:center">
                                    <p:chart type="bar" model="#{performanceStaffController.topperChartModel}" 
                                                rendered="#{performanceStaffController.topperChartModel != null}"
                                                style="#{performanceStaffController.perfBean.chartWidth}"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 10%">
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:outputPanel>
```

I even tried other options like using div etc. but I am no way able to center align the p:chart inside that table-data, it is always left aligned. Please suggest how to center align it.

Note that there is no other problem with any of the components and the chart renders perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.center-block` to make `<p:chart>` element's position center and `.text-center` to make inside text/elements center if any.

```
.center-block {
    display:block;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}

.text-center {text-align:center}
```

Comment: The .center-block css worked perfectly with the above code that is without without the PanelGrid/PanelGroup. Thanks a lot.